# Show first 5 items in list, hide/toggle display of others (PHP)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'd like to show the first 5 names in a list and toggle the display of any additional names as a single block.

I've currently got the names list as an array object though I'm happy to change it to an array if the solution would be simpler with that.

Here's what I have so far which is **in**complete because I don't know how to create the hidden div of names:

PHP

```
  $names_count=0;
  echo '<div id='nameList' class='toggler'>';
  foreach($names as $name){
     echo '<a id='name'.$name->acct_id.'>'.$name->full_name.'</a>';
     if($names_count<=4){
       echo '</div><!--toggler div-->';
     } 
     else
        <div class='namesList' style='display:none'>
         //put additional names in hidden div?
        </div>          
     }
     $names_count++;
  } //endforeach
```

JS:
**UPDATE** Sorry for the confusion. This isn't really a javascript question so I deleted that tag but I'm including the following jQuery code snippet for completeness with the PHP

```
$('.toggler').click(function(){
   var id=this.id;
   $('#'+id).toggle();
});
```

Comment: This is a client-side problem that has nothing to do with PHP. Please show your HTML output, not your server-side code.

Comment: @Diodeus wait what? I'd like to do the counting with PHP.

Comment: What you can do is output them all, hidden, then use JS on the client to expose the ones you want, and provide a link to toggle the rest.

Comment: Isn't it `this.toggle();` instead of `$('#'+id).toggle`?

Comment: thanks, but i'd prefer to keep JS usage minimal

Comment: @ring0 thanks but this isn't a JS, its a PHP one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP

```
$names_count = 0;
echo '<div id="nameList" class="toggler">';
foreach($names as $name) {
    echo '<a id="name' . $name->acct_id . '">' . $name->full_name . '</a>';
    if ($names_count == 4) {
        echo '</div><div class="hidden">';
    }
    $names_count++;
} 
echo '</div>';
```

JS

```
$('.toggler').click(function(){
   $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

CSS

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: This should work.  I would suggest using 2 `while` loops (0 to min(4, N) and 5 to N) instead of a single `foreach`.  It would, in my opinion, make the HTML structure more readable in the PHP code.

Comment: -@upwards shouldn't it be `$(this).children() or $(this).find('.hidden')` instead of `$(this).next()`?

Comment: @MaximeMorin, sounds interesting would you mind showing some code?

Comment: @timpeterson To your question to upwards, no. If you look clearly, he is closing the toggler div and starting the hidden div.  The hidden div is indeed the next div in the structure.  It kinda proves my point about readability...  To your question to me, sure, I will write something down for you.

Comment: @timpeterson, .next() used for get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements.

Comment: @upwards your PHP isn't right. The name `echo`ing part can't come before the counting otherwise all names are just echo'd. There needs to be some kind of conditional `echo`ing here which is what I can't figure out...

Comment: @timpeterson, everything should be ok, for tests try insert this code

`$names = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
$names_count = 0;
echo '<div id="nameList" class="toggler">';
foreach ($names as $name) {
    echo '<div>' . $name . '</div>';
    if ($names_count == 4) {
        echo '</div><div class="hidden">';
    }
    $names_count++;
} 
echo '</div>';`

on this page http://writecodeonline.com/php/

Comment: @timpeterson https://www.evernote.com/shard/s42/sh/c12bedff-83c3-4622-86bb-71bff8be0507/e2fab228bb9d2010a3b9ad2859f60bbe

Comment: @upwards thanks this works! I had already used the className `.hidden` somewhere else in my code which was screwing me up.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example with two `while` loops.

```
$names = array('Bob', 'Andy', 'Tim', 'Max', 'Roger', 'John', 'Test');
$nameCount = count($names);
$nameIndex = 0;

echo '<div id="nameList" class="toggler">'; 

// Show the first 5 names.
while ($nameIndex < min(5, $nameCount)) {
    $name = $names[$nameIndex++];
    echo '<a id="name' . $name . '">' . $name . '</a>';
}

// Show the remaining names in a hidden div.
if ($nameIndex < $nameCount)
{       
    echo '<div class="hiddenNames" style="display:none">';
    while ($nameIndex < $nameCount) {
        $name = $names[$nameIndex++];
        echo '<a id="name' . $name . '">' . $name . '</a>';
    }
    echo '</div>';     
}

echo "</div>";
```

That code produces the following output.

```
<div id="nameList" class="toggler">
    <a id="nameBob">Bob</a>
    <a id="nameAndy">Andy</a>
    <a id="nameTim">Tim</a>
    <a id="nameMax">Max</a>
    <a id="nameRoger">Roger</a>
    <div class="hiddenNames" style="display:none">
        <a id="nameJohn">John</a>
        <a id="nameTest">Test</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

It also safe if you have less than 5 names; the script would produce :

```
<div id="nameList" class="toggler">
    <a id="nameBob">Bob</a>
    <a id="nameAndy">Andy</a>
    <a id="nameTim">Tim</a>
</div>
```

For the JS, I would probably do something along the lines of :

```
$('.toggler').click(function(){
   $('.hiddenNames').toggle();
});
```

Even if the code is a bigger, I find it easier to follow and probably easier to maintain in the long run. (Opinion)

Hope this helps!

Comment: -@Maxime thanks my `$names` is actually a multidimensional array object so unlike with -@upwards solution it's hard for me to adapt your solution to my particular problem. Regardless, thanks for your effort and nice work, I learned something new!

Comment: Maybe there's something I'm not seeing, but it shouldn't be any harder.  From what I'm seeing in your question, you just have to replace these lines `echo '<a id="name' . $name . '">' . $name . '</a>';` by your original line `echo '<a id='name'.$name->acct_id.'>'.$name->full_name.'</a>';`.  It should be working out of the box.  I just didn't want to create an array of objects.  Although, if you found a solution to your problem, I'm happy. :)

Answer (score 0):

To make a `<div>` hidden:

`<div style="display: hidden"></div>`

Then the jQuery should make it visible with the .toggle() command.

Comment: -@Loo thanks but this isn't a JS or CSS question, its a PHP one.